# Confusion with require

Tags: load-path

I started a new question on this topic yesterday, and deleted it because I thought I had it solved. No, I'm still confused about exactly how `require` works. In my situation I have a file `calctest.el` in a path that `load-path` sees. Here is the simple file:

```
(defun calctest ()
  (calc-eval "deg(37@ 26' 36.42\")"))
(provide 'calctest)
```

Now, if I call `(require 'calctest)` in the scratch buffer, I get an error:

```
Required feature `calctest' was not provided". . .
```

This is even after a successful `(load-library "calctest")` and a test to see if it is loaded

```
(calctest) ==>
"37.44345"
```

But if I do a `load-file` on `calctest.el`, then do `(require 'calctest)` it "sees" it and "loads" it (again?). Why will a `require` not simply load my `calctest`? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

> But if I do a `load-file` on `calctest.el`, then do `(require 'calctest)` it "sees" it and "loads" it (again?).

No, the key point is that it *doesn't* load it.

When you `load-file` your calctest.el library, the `(provide 'calctest)` form is evaluated and remembered, which in turn satisfies any subsequent call to `(require 'calctest)` -- regardless of whether or not it would be able to load that library itself.

`require` is essentially just a `load` wrapper which *avoids re-loading* libraries -- it doesn't care (or even know) whether or not they were originally loaded by another call to `require`; just whether `(provide 'FEATURE)` has been evaluated at some point (in which case it loads nothing).

It very much sounds as if your `calctest.el` *wasn't* in your `load-path` when you were originally testing this.

Comment: If I change a library after having done a `require` on it, I need it reloaded. How can I get `require` to redo it? Maybe see my similar question [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/org-babel-like-functionality-outside-of-org-mode).

Comment: You can either call `unload-feature` first, or else simply load it with a non-`require` function. Personally I'd be disinclined to *unload* the feature in this instance unless I was testing the `FEATURE-unload-function` support. `load-library` or `load-file` are typically all I need when re-loading modified code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why will a require not simply load my calctest? What am I missing here?

Perhaps the `path` and a restart. `require` works only if the package is in the `load-path`. `require` also does some filename guessing based on the feature name. Restart `Emacs` may be required to trigger the re-loading.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but what I don't know. Yes, now it appears to be working -- without needing loads of any sort.